# How to describe multiple files in both target and prerequisites

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching

In make, how do I use the wildcard `%` to describe multiple files in both target and prerequisites?

```
%.1: %.md
    for f in $?; do ...; done
```

I thought the above was the way to trigger the rule to create `*.1` files for any `*.md` that were modified since the last run, but shows this instead:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is saying "if you need to make a .1, here is how to do so if you have a .md", you haven't asked make to do any .1.  You probably need also something like:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.md)

all: $(SOURCES:%.md=%.1)

%.1: %.md
    echo $@
```

Note that `*` and `%` are similar (they stands for unspecified characters) but appears in different contexts (`*` to look for existing files, `%` when examining strings -- the strings are often part of file name, but that's not something mandatory and you could for instance use it to match arguments of utilities)

Comment: Thanks. This helped me preventing the error and not having to hardcode the file names in the Makefile. But the left side (`$@`) is always only **1** of the files. How could this be so?

Comment: @JorgeBucaran `$@` refers to the current target, and there is always only one target at any given point. If you need a recipe that processes a bunch of files together then you need to make those files prerequisites of some other target and use `$^`.

Comment: I am still confused about how to do this. Do you mind having a look at this extremely bare example http://pastebin.com/rW0BsWTB? and tell me how I am supposed to automate that with make?

Comment: @JorgeBucaran, see updated answer.  In a rule you are giving instructions about how to make one file from its dependencies. (GNUmake has a file manual, if you intend to write makefiles you better skim over it once so that you know how makes works instead of trying to mix pieces from various sources).

Comment: Thanks! Solved. I think it would be useful for devs coming here in the future explain the difference between `*` and `%` in make. The GNU make manual does not excel at that point or I could not infer it otherwise.

Comment: Also here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219186/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-makefile

Comment: @AProgrammer `$(FISHER_DOC:%.md=%.1)` I didn't know you could use a `:` like that. Where is this bit described in the manual?