# What is the difference between % and * in a makefile

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, gnu-make

The [GNU `make` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) does not excel at explaining this part, I could not find the explanation or I could not infer the information elsewhere.

I realize `%` is a kind of wildcard, but what is the difference between `%` and `*` in the context of `targets`, `dependencies` and `commands`? Where can I use it and does it have the same meaning everywhere?

```
target: dependencies ...
    commands
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wildcard character `*` is used to simply generate a list of matching files in the current directory.  The pattern substitution character `%` is a placeholder for a file which may or may not exist at the moment.

To expand on the [Wildcard pitfall](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Pitfall.html#Wildcard-Pitfall) example from the manual which you had already discovered,

```
objects = *.o
```

The proper way to phrase that if there no '.o' files is something like

```
objects := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
```

`make` itself performs no wildcard expansion in this context, but of course, if you pass the literal value `*.o` to the shell, that's when expansion happens (if there are matches) and so this can be slightly hard to debug.  `make` *will* perform wildcard expansion in the target of a rule, so you can say

```
foo: *.o
```

and have it work exactly like you intended (provided the required files are guaranteed to exist at the time this dependency is evaluated).

By contrast, you can have a rule with a pattern placeholder, which gets filled in with any matching name as `make` tries to find a recipe which can be used to generate a required dependency.  There are built-in rules like

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

(approximating the real thing here) which say "given a file matching `%.c`, the corresponding file `%.o` can be generated as follows."  Here, the `%` is a placeholder which can be replaced by anything; so if it is applied against an existing file `foo.c` it says how `foo.o` can be generated.

You could rephrase it to say `*` matches *every* matching file while `%` matches *any* matching file.

Answer (score 6):

Both `%` and `*` are ordinary characters in Make recipe lines; they are just passed to the shell.

`%` denotes a file "stem" in pattern substitutions, as in `$(patsubst %.o,%.c,$(OBJS))`. The pattern `%.o` is applied to each element in `$(OBJS)`, and `%` captures the matching part. Then in the replacement pattern `%.c`, the captured part is substituted for the `%`, and a list of the substitutions emerges out of `patsubst` as the return value.

`*` is useful in the argument of the `$(wildcard ...)` operator, where it resembles the action of the shell `*` glob in matching some paths in the filesystem.

On the left hand side of a `patsubst`, where `%` denotes a match, it resembles `*` in that it matches some characters. However, `%` carries some restrictions, such as that **it can only appear once**! For instance whereas we can expand the wildcard `*/*.c`, of course, we cannot have a double stem pattern substitution like `$(patsubst %/%.o,%/foo/%.c,...)`.  This restriction could be lifted in some future version of GNU Make, but it currently holds as far as I know.

Also there is a subtle difference between `%` and `*` in that `%` matches a **nonempty** sequence of characters. The wildcard pattern `fo*o.c` matches `foo.c`. The substitution pattern `fo%o.c` does **not** match `foo.c`, because then the stem `%` would be empty which is not allowed.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to match double stem? Could you please help me in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58404646/8428146

Comment: @Z-Y00 You cannot do that; GNU Make matches have a single stem.  Your question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151235/gnu-make-with-multiple-in-pattern-rule from 2016.