# How to match double stem in target like %/% or other way?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to build targets with names like,

```
v1/thread4/foo  v1/thread8/foo v1/thread16/foo
v2/thread4/foo  v2/thread8/foo v2/thread16/foo
```

I want to match the **thread%** and **v%**, because for my code, the threadNum=? and the Version=? are the Macros need to define in the compile time.
so in the result, I hope to get a layout like, and the foo is the executable name

```
v1-|thead4/foo
   |thead8/foo
   |thead16/foo
v2-|thead4/foo
   |thead8/foo
   |thead16/foo
```

I've tried ways like, it doesn't work

```
%/%/foo: foo.cc $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DTHREAD=$* -o $@ $< $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: Can you clarify 'it doesn't work' ? What is the output/error message ?

Comment: @dash-o well, as the answer pointed out, the gun make just doesn't support this, so I gave up and use other tricks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy when you realise that `$@` is `v1/thread4/foo` (say),
to then pull out the bits you need.

In this case, something like:

```
v = $(firstword $(subst /, ,$@))
thread = $(notdir ${@D})
```

YMMV of course. leading to

```
targets := \
  v1/thread4/foo v1/thread8/foo v1/thread16/foo \
  v2/thread4/foo v2/thread8/foo v2/thread16/foo

all: ${targets}

v = $(firstword $(subst /, ,$@))
thread = $(notdir ${@D})

${targets}:
    : '$@: v [$v] thread [${thread}]'
```

giving

```
$ make
: 'v1/thread4/foo: v [v1] thread [thread4]'
: 'v1/thread8/foo: v [v1] thread [thread8]'
: 'v1/thread16/foo: v [v1] thread [thread16]'
: 'v2/thread4/foo: v [v2] thread [thread4]'
: 'v2/thread8/foo: v [v2] thread [thread8]'
: 'v2/thread16/foo: v [v2] thread [thread16]'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have multiple patterns in GNU make.

If your example above is actually reflective of what you want to do, it's simple enough, though:

```
VLIST := 1 2
TLIST := 4 8 16

TARGETS := $(foreach V,$(VLIST),$(foreach T,$(TLIST),v$V/thread$T/foo))

$(TARGETS): foo.cc $(HEADERS)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DTHREAD=$* -o $@ $< $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: Does this work? What does `$*` expand to in the recipe?

Comment: Right, you will likely need to use make functions to extract what you need from `$@`, rather than using `$*`.